# Why does passing a Column Transformer object through a pipeline does not work, but passing a simple object does

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scikit-learn, data-science

So apparently making a column transformer object of StandardScaler and passing it through the pipeline from sklearn throws an error, but passing StandardScaler() on it's substitution works fine.

```
>>ohe = ColumnTransformer([
    ('OHE',OneHotEncoder(sparse=False,handle_unknown='ignore',drop='first'),[0,4,5,6])
],remainder='passthrough')

>>ss = ColumnTransformer([
    ('scale',StandardScaler())
])

>>lr=LinearRegression()

>>pipe = Pipeline([
    ('ohe',ohe),
    ('ss',ss),
    ('LR',lr)
])

>>pipe.fit(X_train,y_train)
## this throws an error
```

[image]

But this doesn't??

```
>>ohe = ColumnTransformer([
    ('OHE',OneHotEncoder(sparse=False,handle_unknown='ignore',drop='first'),[0,4,5,6])
],remainder='passthrough')

>>ss = ColumnTransformer([
    ('scale',StandardScaler())
])

>>lr=LinearRegression()

>>pipe = Pipeline([
    ('ohe',ohe),
    ('ss',StandardScaler()),
    ('LR',lr)
])

>>pipe.fit(X_train,y_train)
```

[image]

Can someone tell me why and how of it?